# How to log out from google account in android ?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am developing application that uses login using google Auth2.0 with android account manager. I am login successfully and fetching data from my google using different apis but I don't know about how to log out from my application and when logout want to shows login screen  once again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can log-out, you will have to show the AccountChooser again

try

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[] {"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
 startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks but what is "SOME_REQUEST_CODE" parameter.please,can you give me e.g

Comment: You can make this up yourself, but try 6789

Answer (score 1):

Usually i saved the account name on SharedPreferences and on log-out just remove the account name from the SharedPreferences. Saving the account name from **onActivityResult**

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
                    //do the rest after saving the account name on SharedPreferences
                }
            }
```

And log out(my log out occur on a different activity):

```
private void logOut(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME,null)!=null){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        editor.commit();
        //here show the log-in screen again
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey What is "PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME" parameter

Comment: its just a string variable, like: final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

Answer (score 1):

While logging in you have saved data i.e. your access token in shared preferenes. So when you want to LogOut clear shared preferences. It is the only way to logout.